# How to make a cell editable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently trying to give user the ability to edit the content of the multiple cells. Once updated, the data will be sent to web service.

Ok right now, as far as I have read, there is only "delete" and "add" row(s). I can't seem to find any guides or tutorials on how to edit the content of cell(s).

Your suggestion(s) and/or advices are much appreciated.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}
```

Comment: That's not how you spell Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not edit cell content directly. If you need to edit content then add `UITextField` or `UITextView` in cell as its subview. and then access them.

EDIT : You can add textfield as below :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        // ADD YOUR TEXTFIELD HERE
        UITextField *yourTf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 330.0f, 30)];
        [yourTf setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        yourTf.tag = 1;
        yourTf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
        yourTf.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0f/255.0f green:61.0f/255.0f blue:61.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        yourTf.delegate = self;
        [cell addSubview:yourTf];

    }

    // ACCESS YOUR TEXTFIELD BY REUSING IT
    [(UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1] setText:@"YOUR TEXT"];

    return cell;
}
```

Implement UITextField delegates and then you can edit cell content using this UITextField.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That makes sense. I shall try that out first.

Comment: Not yet. Is there a shorter way to do it on a static table without making a custom cell?

Comment: Check my edited answer. I have added a textfield as an example for your understanding. I will work for you.

Comment: I do not think that I can use that because I am using "configureView()" to configure my static cells. If I were to uncomment your suggested method, as well as the section and row methods, I would receive a couple of errors which I have no idea on how to solve it. Nevertheless, I am doing a mockup as per suggested by adding a view, and putting a UITextView inside it. I am able to see the data, however, I have no idea on how to edit it in such away that I do not need to scroll to see the whole text. Any idea? I have tried sizeToFit to no avail.